Creating flowgarithm for user-defined datatypes
I want to create a flowgarithm but my c program uses enum and structures quite often. Is there any symbol to allow the flowgarithm to work?
I tried many but it was not successful.
struct Loan {
    float amount;    
    float interestRate;    
    char collateral[50];    
    int isApproved;
};

There seems to be no in-built representation for the same. I tried to create using some of the conditionals present, but the output is incomplete either way.

What can I do?
Can I create my own symbols?
What do I do to get the output?


I am not aware what a flowgarithm is. Please consider to describe what you want to achieve, using more and different words. I suspect that you want to do something which C++ is better for, at least if it is polymorphism or the like. Consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

The documentation for Flowgorithm shows the only data types it has are integer, real, string, and Boolean. No mention of enumerations or structures is made. Flowgorithm looks like a small project never sufficiently developed for use in serious projects. I do not expect it supports enumerations or structures.
